# Gitlab Double pipeline triggering issue

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

When pushing a commit two pipeline jobs are triggered. But the same thing has not occurred when starting the pipeline manually.

Where I should check?
What is the meaning of the arrow from the left or from the right indicating branch activities?

One thing I have to say is that there is a merge request pending, does it cause this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The thing with your solution is that it only avoids pipeline execution when you have a merge request event, but there still will be duplicate pipelines, e.g. merge-request pipelines (the `detached` ones) and branch pipelines (others), also when pushing a tag your setup will create a separate pipeline I think.

Following the docs you can avoid duplicate pipelines and switch between Branch- and MR-Pipelines when using the following rules-set for workflow (I added the `|| $CI_COMMIT_TAG`) since when pushing a tag also a pipeline should be created (but maybe only a few jobs will be added into this pipeline)

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' || '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
```

this pipeline is a merge-request pipeline, you can see this because it's `detached` and because of the Merge-Request Symbol and the number of the MR on the left hand side of the commit id

[image: merge-request pipeline]

The following screenshot shows a 'normal' branch-pipeline, which is denoted by the branch-name and the GitLab branch symbol on the left of your commit id

[image: branch-pipeline]

Answer (score 2):

Pending merge request cause second pipeline jobs triggered. After adding the following into `gitlab-ci.yml file`  it is resolved

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Comment: The first rule does not avoid duplications in your pipeline, it only avoids pipelines from being generated on opening a merge-request, see answer below for further info and updated rule-set, but this is a quite tricky topic where I already spent lots of hours fixing duplicate pipelines