# Difference between different GitLab CI Merge Request rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

As several other users, I'm facing issues with [duplicate pipelines in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#avoid-duplicate-pipelines). While there is some documentation on how to prevent this scattered around in the GitLab docs,
my impression is that the indivdual docs pages and sections are rather inconsistent.

My question is, what are the differences between the following rules? Or, more specifically, are there cases in which these rules are evaluated differently?

- [Switch between branch pipelines and merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines) suggest this to identify merge request pipelines:

  ```yaml
  if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  ```
- Additionally, [Switch between branch pipelines and merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines) also uses this rule in combination with `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH &&`:

  ```yaml
  if: '$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
  ```
- Moreover, the [MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Workflows/MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml) uses a third rule:

  ```yaml
  if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
  ```

Any explanation or hints to docs pages I might have overlooked is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to avoid duplicate pipeline creation and the requirement that you want to switch between Branch-Pipelines and Merge-Request-Pipelines I recommend using these `workflow rules`

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' || '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
```

There is another SO-question that asks how to prevent duplicate pipelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70203979/gitlab-double-pipeline-triggering-issue/70206389#70206389)

#### The Explanation(s):

In the following section I will try to explain your different rules and how GitLab CI will evaluate them during pipeline creation.

##### The `merge_request_event`-rule

Using this rule:

```yaml
if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

will create a pipeline each time a Merge-Request is created/updated, but there will also be a pipeline created for the branch if you do not have another prevention mechanism (rule).
As the variable naming also points out, this is about the source of the pipeline trigger, other sources could be `schedule`, `push`, `trigger` etc.

##### The `CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` variable:

Using a rule like:

```yaml
if: '$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
```

GitLab will create new pipelines if there is an open Merge-Request for this branch. Pipelines because there will be a Merge-Request pipeline (denoted with the `detached` flag) and a branch pipeline for the branch you pushed changes.

```yaml
if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
```

This rule above will create a pipeline for your branch when, and only when there is an open MR on that branch.

```yaml
if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
when: never
```

When using the above combination no pipeline will be created if there are open Merge-Requests on that branch, which might also be undesirable since the CI should run tests for branches and/or Merge-Requests.

**But how to be able to have pipelines for MRs and Branches, but prevent duplications in pipeline creation?**

```yaml
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
  when: never
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' || '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
```

With this rule set above GitLab will create pipelines for branches and Merge-Requests (the `detached` ones), as well as pipelines for git-`tags`, but it will prevent GitLab from duplicating pipelines.
The last rule evaluates to true either when there is a commit to a branch or there is a git-tag.

#### Further links

- Official [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines) on switching between MR- and Branch-Pipelines
- Docs on how to [avoid](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#avoid-duplicate-pipelines) duplicate pipelines with rules examples

Comment: Thanks, I think I know understand the difference between `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"` and `$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS`. One point your answer left open is the `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` variable, used in the [official workflow for MR pipelines](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Workflows/MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml). Do you know what is the difference between `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` and `$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS`?

Comment: For our *workflow*, we're using the following *rules*:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

This way, we expect to also run scheduled or manual pipelines. Could there be anything wrong with this configuration?

Comment: Using the rule `if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` is basically the same as a non-nullish check of the variable. This means, if the variable is not null (which would be the case when no MR is present for the current branch) then a pipeline will be created.

Your workflow is valid way to handle job-limiting but I think there might be cases where your workflow might create duplicate pipelines, e.g. a tagged commit being pushed to a branch with no open MR. But it might be that I am wrong with that assumption

Comment: Hello @SPMSE, With the above workflow rules, how to avoid the job not to run on Main branch? After a MR from branch to Main. Still that job get executed.?

Comment: @Sanjeev you would need to add a new rule, like so:

- if: $CI_COMMIT_SOURCE == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
   when: never

This rule should be added to the respective job as first rule within the rules list.